# Binarization in excel

Tags: excel, data-mining, worksheet-function, data-analysis

How would you perform binarization of an attribute with five categorical values in excel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading that as: you need to map one of five input values onto one of two output values.

To do this, set up a two-column table in Excel. The first column should list each input value and the second column should list the output value which that input value should map to.

In your actual dataset, use a `VLOOKUP` to translate from input to output.

Here's an example:

[image: Excel spreadsheet showing character names from The Simpsons being binarized into genders]

In the example, the formula in C4 is `=VLOOKUP(B4,$G$4:$H$8,2,FALSE)`. Note that the title row of the mapping table is not included in the lookup range